# uint8_t and unsigned char linking error

Tags: c++, function, char, overloading, unsigned

I'm using template function:

```
template<typename T> void func(const T& value)
{
    obj->func(value);
}
```

where obj is object of class:

```
void my_object::func(int64_t value) { ... }
void my_object::func(uint64_t value) { ... }
void my_object::func(uint32_t value) { ... }
void my_object::func(uint16_t value) { ... }
void my_object::func(uint8_t value) { ... }
```

The problem is with **uint8_t** overload of **my_object::func()** override. Linker complains about unresolved external symbols to overloads, which *should* have **unsigned char** parameter.

Should I replace **uint8_t** overload with **unsigned char** overload?

Edit: Just now noticed, that linker complains about **uint64_t** and **int64_t** too.

I compile on Windows using **MSVC++ 2008 Express**.

Edit: Apologies, I *declared* **my_object::func(uint8_t value)** function (and other), but I *didn't defined* it.

Comment: Incidentally, what is your compiler?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you're getting?

Comment: You should try to reduce the problem scope and give more details on what you are actually doing. Is it really because of the template - what happens if you make a direct call of obj::func() instead? How do you define your class, and where and how you have it implemented? With only the description that you provided people would have to guess what is actually happening.

Comment: Make sure you use the same headers and thus typedefs of those integer types. MSVC has defects with how it resolves equivalent types. In certain cases two types are C++ identical but MSVC has distinct internal types for them. Those internal types make it to the linker, thus a mismatch.

Answer (score 8):

This is the `include` file should #include to use the above mentioned types (C99 recommendations)

[#include](http://linux.die.net/man/3/uint32_t) <stdint.h>

Comment: It leads to *link* errors because the include you have to `#include` will not have converted before compilation via the `typedef` declarations all the int32... In other terms, during compilation all the above mentioned special types do not exist anymore - thus they are not present during *linking* either.

Comment: `stdint.h` was included into C99 in order to help programs portability. It is also available on Windows. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h

Comment: Should really be **#include <cstdint>** for C++ programs. That header isn't included with VS2008, but you can find a compatible file in several places on the 'net.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `uint8_t` has been `typedef`ed as `unsigned char`, hence why you're seeing that.

Comment: Looking at the source, no. uint8_t is typedef for UINT8.

Comment: hm.. I am not sure but `uint8_t` belongs to `stdint.h` which purpose is to abstract away from primitive types which might in turn be different in different platforms.

Comment: The library I'm working with has include file, which differentiate between build environments. If it's windows it defines all int types manually, if Linux it includes stdint.h and inttypes.h

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling with

```
template void my_object::func(int64_t value) { ... }
template void my_object::func(uint64_t value) { ... }
template void my_object::func(uint32_t value) { ... }
template void my_object::func(uint16_t value) { ... }
template void my_object::func(uint8_t value) { ... }
```

fixed my problem with a similar issues